# Get value of first key in nested json object using SQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

Json format as

```
{
  "query": {
    "pages": {
      "294195": {
        "id": 294195,
        "title": "title 123",
        "detail": "detail content..."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to read the `294195`, and detail info under this element.

But actually the element name '294195' is dynamic.

I can not use  `294195` as element name:

```
"Json"->'query'->'pages'->'294195'
```

Is there anyway like

```
"Json"->'query'->'pages'->Firt_Element_Name->'id'
```

note: `"Json"` is a column name and type as Json.

Comment: You'll probably have to unpack the json object with `json_each` and `row_number` in a lateral query, then pick the first row. Awkward. Or use `json_object_keys` in a subquery to get the first key. What you really want is a proper json query expression system, like xpath for json. A few people are working on one for PostgreSQL but it's not yet included.

Comment: Also, note that really json objects don't have a logical order. You cannot rely on the key being "first". Do you actually want the one that appears first in the object? Or the one with lowest numeric value?

Answer (score 0):

```
Json.query.pages[0].title
Json.query.pages[0].details
```

Gives first key-pair value for "title" and first key-pair value for "details" regardless of what the first generated No. is.  This works regardless of the # you get dynamically.  Pop it into a function and you can set them as var's and concatenate them into a string, or push them into an array/object.

Comment: Will this (dot method) work in  Postgresql?  it doesn't recognize.Your method more like .net

Comment: Well I was just labeling the dot notation to get to your element, not writing out specific copy and paste code as Barbara Laird edited a dot notation to "code snippet" as. Sorry she reformatted my response to make you believe it was actual code.  I would need to know what language you are using to hit your Postgresql database from to give you valid copy+paste code.

Comment: In the original post it's code within PostgreSQL its self, SQL queries with operators to access the json structure. I suggest deleting this answer, as it doesn't help the user and will discourage other people from replying.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little awkward b/c I had to create your original json object before I could query against it, but here is a PostgreSQL cut and paste solution that will extract the data under 294195:

```
with origjson as (select '{"query": {"pages": {"294195": {"id": 294195,"title": "title 123","detail": "detail content..."}}}}'::jsonb as pagedata)
,firstid as (select jsonb_object_keys(pagedata #> '{query, pages}') as id from origjson)
select pagedata #> ('{query, pages, ' || (select id from firstid limit 1) || '}')::text[] from origjson;
```

Result:

```
{"id": 294195, "title": "title 123", "detail": "detail content..."}
```